# Unable to install nvidia driver - kernel error

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, graphics, ubuntu-mate

I have a toshiba tecra M2 laptop. It has the nvidia geforce FX go5200 graphics in it.

To install its driver I went here to download the correct display driver for my device: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/71302/en-us

Then followed this guide step by step to install my driver: http://www.allaboutlinux.eu/remove-nouveau-and-install-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu-15-04/2/

But I am given the error:

> error: unable to build the nvidia kernel module.

I would appreciate some help. I want to install this legacy driver as I am getting problems while streaming videos and think maybe this driver fixes it.

edit:

the possible duplicate question is for installing the latest nvidia driver, I want to install this specific legacy driver as my card is no longer supported